# Bootstrap js not working with a jsp file in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, jakarta-ee

The Bootstrap CSS wasn't working, it only worked after using <%=request.getContextPath()%>, I did the same to the Javascript but it isn't working.

Here is a part of my jsp file, it has the bootstrap nav-bar, I only changed the head content :

```html
%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    
 ....
```

Files structure :

[image: files structure]

So the issue is that the Bootstrap CSS works but the Javascript doesn't, and  I don't know what could be the reason. 
I have tried modifying that path, but in vain.

Comment: please try adding jquery lib before bootstrap.js

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt Thank you, it worked after adding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery lib.

So, adding jquery lib before bootstrap.js may be enough to fix the issue.